# onchange event in textbox wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me how to make how to make a onchange event in input work after I searched in textbox.

My problem is: it's not working I tried the `keydown` , `blur` and the jquery but still it doesn't work on me I need your help guys.

html code:

```
<input onkeydown="updateTextboxes()" class="search_textbox" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="search" id="query" />
```

I tried using the jquery `$('#query').change(updateTextboxes);` but it doesn't work :(

script code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $funiq_id = $('#funiq_id'),
        $t_region = $('#t_region'),
        $t_town = $('#t_town'),
        $t_uniq_id = $('#t_uniq_id'),
        $t_position = $('#t_position'),
        $t_salary_grade = $('#t_salary_grade'),
        $t_salary = $('#t_salary');

    function updateTextboxes() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {term: $('#query').val()},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(result) {
                var ii = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    $funiq_id.html(result[i].value).show();
                    $t_region.val(result[i].region).show().trigger('input');
                    $t_town.val(result[i].town).show().trigger('input');
                    $t_uniq_id.val(result[i].uniq_id).show().trigger('input');
                    $t_position.val(result[i].position).show().trigger('input');
                    $t_salary_grade.val(result[i].salary_grade).show().trigger('input');
                    $t_salary.val(result[i].salary).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#id' + ii + '').val(result[i].atid).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#aic' + ii + '').val(result[i].atic).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#name' + ii + '').val(result[i].atname).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#other_qual' + ii + '').val(result[i].other_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#interview' + ii + '').val(result[i].interview_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#optA' + ii + '').val(result[i].edu_attain2_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#optB' + ii + '').val(result[i].experience2_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#optC' + ii + '').val(result[i].trainings2_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#optD' + ii + '').val(result[i].eligibility2_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $('#total' + ii + '').val(result[i].final_total_sum).show().trigger('input');
                    $(':input').removeAttr('placeholder');
                    ii++;
                }
            }
        });
    };
    $('.search_form_input').val('');
    $('.search_textbox').val('');
    $(".empty_batchcode").html("");
    $('#execute').prop('disabled', true);
});      
</script>
```

Comment: are you getting errors on your console? And what event is `input` (from `.trigger("input")`)

Comment: i didnt get any error and those trigger are for the inputboxes that will be filed with data after the script work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a updateTextboxes() not defined error. Remove `onkeydown="updateTextboxes()"` from your html code and add this to your jquery function:

```
$('.search_textbox').on('keydown', function(){

      updateTextboxes()  
})
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Su9Uv/

Answer (score 1):

in your `$(document).ready(function() {` try this:

```
var updateTextboxes = function () {[...]}
$('#query').change(updateTextboxes);
```

Your code:

```
<input onkeydown="updateTextboxes()" class="search_textbox" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="search" id="query" />
```

doesn't work because the function `updateTextboxes` isn't in the main scope

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#query').on('change', updateTextboxes);


$('#query').on('input', updateTextboxes);
```

- Listening for the "input" event will trigger any time the input is modified (Even on paste).

  Note: The "Input" event should only be used if legacy browser support is not an issue.